# Difficulty with multiple overlaying textures on one material

Tags: cycles-render-engine, uv, node-editor, displacement

I feel like this is quite a long winded and complicated issue but I really appreciate any help I can get!

(I have included the blender file at the bottom for reference.)

I am making a cloth object which has lots of different sections and textures. To keep the geometry as simple as possible I am attempting to paint on the textures using multiple image masks on the same material and UV mask in order to keep the geometry intact. Here's where I am at so far to give you an idea of what I am going for, I have made decent progress but it's getting quite complex:

[image: Above view of robe]
[image: Dynamic view of robe]
[image: Full view of node editor]

I'm fairly new to the node editor and blender in general so this is already getting over my head. The main difficulty I am having at the moment however is firstly where to connect my displacement outputs in my bump maps. I connected the first one to the displacement input on the material output node which had an effect (although I feel it might have had an effect over the whole object instead of just the painted map)

[image: View of connected displacement output]

but now that slot is occupied I don't know where to connect my other ones:

[image: View of loose displacement output 1]
[image: View of loose displacement output 1]

The second problem is fairly related. I want to have some of the patterns that are "printed" on top of my cloth to be slightly raised. I am guessing this is probably done by applying a bump node to the mask but I'm not really sure how to achieve it. Here for example is the image texture node containing the black and white mask I used for one of the yellow patterned sections at the top of the cloth:

[image: Image texture]

I would like to have this raised very slightly to make it a bit more dynamic but can't figure it out.

Thanks for bearing through that explanation, I hope I have explained it with enough clarity and again I appreciate any help that can be offered!

Here is the blender file: [image]

Answer (score 1):

There are several choices to make multiples bumps on one object.

1. Make it via the different shaders.
   Not relevant in your case because Chocofur fabric shaders don't have input for normals/bumps, so you would need to modify all shaders.
2. Make it via different materials.
   Would need more work at this step.
3. **Make it in the material by combining several bumps maps.**
   The picture explain it well I think:

[image]